# MDB2, Pear, Mysql error

Tags: mysql, pear, mdb2

I have PEAR, MDB2 and Mysql Driver installed however I keep getting:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function:
MDB2_Driver_mysql::_isNewLinkSet().
in /home/********/PEAR/MDB2.php on line 1937.
```

The Server is CentOS

I am stuck, any help would be appriciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have either http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2_Driver_mysql/ or http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2_Driver_mysqli/ installed? It's not clear whether you do or not - though I suspect you do (otherwise you'd be getting a different error)

Which version of MDB2_Driver_mysql do you have?

Comment: Version 1.4.1 (MDB2_Driver_mysql)

Comment: You appear to be using the most recent release of MDB2_Driver_mysql but not the most recent version of MDB2; I'd suggest upgrading to the most recent release and see if that might resolve the issue.

Comment: We have the following versions:

MDB2 - 2.4.1
MDB2_Driver_mysql - 1.4.1

Comment: 2.4.1 is close to two years old; I'd really suggest you upgrade to 1.5.0b2 of MDB2_Driver_mysql and version 2.5.0b2 of MDB2.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.

Decided to rewrite the whole backend using PDO.

+1

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem,
Reinstall the two last version Beta (for now)
and it will be fine.

```
$ pear upgrade mdb2-beta mdb2_driver_mysqli-beta
```

Comment: Nailed it! In 2022 this gets it working with PHP7.4!

Answer (score 0):

Just had this happen to me, make sure your version of MDB2 matches the version of the sql/sqli drivers.   I had to unsintall and force PEAR to install the beta channel inorder to get them to match